# Keycloak and React infinite redirect

Tags: reactjs, keycloak

We're using Keycloak 10.0.0 on a remote, secure server in a React application. The issue is that after a successful login, the app goes into an infinite redirect loop, alternating between the root url

```
http://localhost:3000/dashboard/
```

and this url

```
http://localhost:3000/dashboard/#state=04604595-e7ca-49ba-8a61-10f851cef979&session_state=362099d1-9e4e-43d6-8062-c48a31a0b216&code=0997e564-6419-49be-9f34-8bbf718163b6.362099d1-9e4e-43d6-8062-c48a31a0b216.aff4ee58-1a22-4bc5-88f9-9f586933b13e
```

This is how we're initializing Keycloak in the app:

```
import Keycloak, { KeycloakConfig } from 'keycloak-js';

const keycloak = Keycloak({
    'url': the_authentication_server,
    'clientId': the_client_id,
    'confidential-port': 0,
    'public-client': true,
    'realm': the_realm,
    'resource': the_client_id,
    'ssl-required': 'external',
} as KeycloakConfig);

keycloak.init({
    checkLoginIframe: false,
    pkceMethod: 'S256',
    silentCheckSsoFallback: false,
});

export default keycloak;
```

And these are the relevant package versions:

```
"@react-keycloak/web": "^3.4.0",
"keycloak-js": "10.0.0",
```

Re-enabling the use of the iframe is impossible due to security concerns. Can anyone spot an issue?

Thanks!

Comment: This happens in react 18 with string mode [GitHub react-keycloak](https://github.com/react-keycloak/react-keycloak/issues/182). For me as a workaround putting StrictMode inside ReactKeycloakProvider worked. But some people complained that it doesn't work for them. Worth a try.

Answer (score -1):

I investigated the issue because I had same issue. And the issue is in the '@react-keycloak/web' library, especially it the context provider. Therefore, I would not suggest using this library. For the integration the keycloak I used [this boilerpalte](https://github.com/dasniko/keycloak-reactjs-demo). A pretty sure that '@react-keycloak/web' does not under support. Please see the last update date.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).